# JavaFX tree view showing default selection

Tags: java, treeview, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

I am using JavaFX8.

I have a tree view and it contains some objects.

The tree view gets displayed with all the nodes expanded.

I would like to have a default item on the treeview selected when the UI startsup.

I have tried the following but it doesn't work.

```
rootNode.setExpanded(true);
popupTree.setShowRoot(false);
popupTree.setRoot(rootNode);
popupTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(SelectionMode.SINGLE);

popupTree.requestFocus();
popupTree.getSelectionModel().select(new TreeItem<FinancialAccount>(selectedAccount));
popupTree.getFocusModel().focus(popupTree.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
```

If I replace the code with a static integer value like this

```
popupTree.requestFocus();
popupTree.getSelectionModel().select(5);
popupTree.getFocusModel().focus(5);
```

This selects the 5th item on the tree and its highlighted on the UI.

To determine the index of the object in the tree, I am using the methods in my first snippet, they always return -1

Obviously the select(object) method in the SelectionModel class is not correctly evaluating the passed object. I tried overriding the equals method in my FinancialAccount Object but it doesn't make a difference.

Any thoughts on how to get this working

Comment: You're passing a `TreeItem` that is not part of your `TreeView`.

Comment: The tree item I am passing is an object that was used in creating the tree, i.e myobject is the object used to create TreeItem myt = new TreeItem(myobject);mytree.setroot(myt); While comparing I am again using the same myobject to create a new instance of treeitem.

Comment: The selection model is going to look at the `TreeItem` you passed, not its value. You need to pass the same `TreeItem` instance, not merely one that contains the same data.

Comment: Thanks it works after using the same instance as you suggested